# Replace duplicate content of span using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have button in my html page and lots of jquery libraries included on this page I am getting a issue like when I open page on live server then its changing the html text and making duplicate text like I have on html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Quote" name="submit">
```

After live it its converting into:

```
<span>Get Quote <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" name="submit"></span>
```

Span automatically coming even its not in code.

And

```
<select id='list' name='list'>
    <option value='0'>Select Numbers</option>
    <option value='my number'>my Number</option>
</select>
```

Its coming on live like this:

```
<span>Select Numbers
<select id='list' name='list'>
<option value='0'>Select Numbers</option>
<option value='my number'>my Number</option>
</select>
</span>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "open page as live"?

Comment: I mean when I run it on live server

Comment: Answering this depends on why the `<span>` is appearing in the first place.

Comment: That is my question actually

Comment: There may be some javascripts(like jquery libs) generating `<span>` automaticly

Comment: `and lots of jquery libraries included on this page` btw this question is not clear. You certainly may have to look into plugins, Maybe one of your plugins is adding it on input elements.

Comment: Might be possible but how can I check which one is generating <span> and how can I stop them ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS to remove the text.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var z = new Array();
for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; ++x){
    if(inputs[x].parentNode.textContent.trim() == inputs[x].value.trim()){
        var input = inputs[x];
        input.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(input, input.parentNode);
    }
}
```

```html
<span>Text <input type="button" value="Text" /></span><br />
<span>Some Field Name <input type="button" value="Some Field Name" /></span>
```

However, figuring out why the span is appearing in the first place, and removing that part of the code would be a much better and cleaner idea.

Comment: Are you putting it after your page has loaded? It can't remove something that isn't there yet.

Comment: I tried to put it before head tag close its not working then I try to put it before body tag close but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just removing the library from my page;

```
http://www.hccmis.com/wp-content/themes/hccmis-2/js/waypoints.min.js
```

And its working for me.